# How to force Java JSON or GSON to explicitly name my arrays and objects

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following POJO:

```
public class Widget {
    private String fizz;
    private String buzz;
    private String foo;

    // Getters and setters for all 3...
}
```

In my code, I am trying to convert a `List<List<Widget>>` into JSON using the [Java JSON](http://json.org/java/) library (however I'd also accept any answer using GSON as well).

Here is my code:

```
// Returns a single List<Widget> with 2 Widgets in it...
List<List<Widget>> widgetGroups = getWidgetGroups();

String widgetGroupsAsJson = JSON.encode(widgetGroups);
System.out.println(widgetGroupsAsJson);
```

This prints:

```
[
    [
        {
            "fizz": "Yes",
            "buzz": "Never",
            "foo": "Always"
        },
        {
            "fizz": "Sometimes",
            "buzz": "Always",
            "foo": "Pending"
        }
    ]
]
```

Whereas I want the JSON to appear as:

```
"widgetGroups": [
    "widgetGroup": [
        "widget": {
            "fizz": "Yes",
            "buzz": "Never",
            "foo": "Always"
        },
        "widget": {
            "fizz": "Sometimes",
            "buzz": "Always",
            "foo": "Pending"
        }
    ]
]
```

In other words, I want all the lists, as well as each `widget`, to be "named". My first concern, however, is that this may not be proper JSON. When I paste this 2nd (desired) JSON snippet into [jsonlint.org](http://jsonlint.org) I get a parser error.

So **first** I'm asking if someone could be so kind as to point out what my desired JSON *should* look like in order to be proper; and then **second** if someone could help me massage my `widgetGroups` list so that either Java JSON or GSON can produce the desired output. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, are you sure this is correct? The comment and code does not match .

```
// Returns a single List<Widget> with 2 Widgets in it...
List<List<Widget>> widgetGroups = getWidgetGroups();
```

Second, create a WidgetGroup class that will act as a container for a single WidgetGroup.

```
public class WidgetGroup {

    private String name;
    private List<Widget> widgets;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Widget> getWidgets() {
        return widgets;
    }

    public void setWidgets(List<Widget> widgets) {
        this.widgets = widgets;
    }
}
```

This would be a valid JSON structure:

```
{
  "widgetGroups" : [
    {
      "widgetGroup": [
        "widget": {
          "fizz": "Yes",
          "buzz": "Never",
          "foo": "Always"
        },
        /*More widgets*/
      ]
    },
    /*More widget groups*/
  ]
}
```

Something like this should work:

```
Map<String, List<WidgetGroup>> widgetGroups = new HashMap<String, List<WidgetGroup>>();
WidgetGroup widgetGroup1 = getWidgetGroup(); // Just an assumption of one of your methods.
WidgetGroup widgetGroup2 = getWidgetGroup(); // Just an assumption of one of your methods.

List<WidgetGroup> widgetGroupList = new ArrayList<WidgetGroup>();
widgetGroupList.add(widgetGroup1);
widgetGroupList.add(widgetGroup2);

widgetGroups.put("widgetGroups", widgetGroupList);
```

Then you call `toJson()` on the map.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON there are only two types of "containers" - arrays, which are implicitly ordered but not named, and object (or associative arrays), which are not necessarily ordered but have named key-value pairs. The correct JSON syntax should be:

```
{
  "widgetGroups": [
    {
      "widgetGroup": [
        {
            "fizz": "Yes",
            "buzz": "Never",
            "foo": "Always"
        },
        {
            "fizz": "Sometimes",
            "buzz": "Always",
            "foo": "Pending"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You should note that inside the "widgetGroup" list i placed an array - you either must give up names and put up a simple array (**[]** syntax), or an object (**{}** syntax) **and** use unique names (i.e. you can't have two identical elements named "widget")

As for the syntax to get this from GSON (or other common java-json transformers) use maps instead of lists where you want an associative array.

**Edit**: I've not worked previously with JSON-Java but looking at the specs it seems you need the *JSONObject* class to insert associative arrays.